# How to do HttpWebRequests from a Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I've been looking for an answer to my problem for several days, but sadly had no luck. I hope you guys here can help me out.

So, what I want to do is just a simple call against the delicious.com API that returns me the recent bookmarks ("posts" in delicious terminology). Therefore you simply use the following  [URI](https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/recent?) and enter your credentials for logging in to delicious.com.

When I do this from a standard .NET4 Console Application with the magic of HttpWebRequest and setting the Credentials, it works as expected. Trying to do the same basic HttpWebRequest on the WP7 emulator leads to an WebException stating that "The remote server returned an error: NotFound.".
When diving deeper into this exception I can see that my Response has a StatusDescription of "Unauthorized". It seems like no authentication happend at all.

Next I tried - as I read that setting the Credentials sometiemes leads to problems - was to directly set the "Authorization" RequestHeader. Guess what, the result was the same.

I ended up with the following code and without ideas. I hope, somebody here is able to 
help me out and point a way, how I can reach my bookmarks from my WP7.

```
public void RetrieveRecentBookmarks(string userName, string password)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(requestString);

    byte[] bytes = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password)
    string authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authInfo;

    RequestState state = new RequestState(request);
    IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, state);
}

private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    RequestState state = asynchronousResult.AsyncState as RequestState;
    HttpWebRequest request = state.Request as HttpWebRequest;

    // Here is where it breaks...
    HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've found times when the emulator will not work with the web. Usually I confirm that it's a emulator problem by trying to use the emulator browser. It will usually fail. If you have an actual phone, try debugging through that. Another test is to see if you get a result back if you hit something like bing.com.

Comment: The emulator's browser works just fine, every time I give it a try. Also, when going to bing.com my WebRequest returns happily.

As this is the first application I'm developing for WP7 I'm not a registered developer yet, so debuggin on the device is not yet an option.
I probably should spend the 99$ instead of wasting even more time with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I now know, my code is absolutely correct and working. What was not working was the Emulator communication, as already mentioned by Shawn Kendrot.
I set up a completely fresh Win7, installed the WP7.1 SDK (and 7.1.1 Update) and it works like expected. So it seems like something blocked my calls from the emulator. I've got no idea, what it was, but I must admit, I don't care too much as it is working now.

Thank you Shawn for pointing out that there are sometimes problems with the Emulator and the web, that kicked me into the right direction.